# Uninstall Linux on an embedded board

Tags: linux, embedded

I am using an embedded board, a FOX G20 V with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20 processor. I would like to know first of all, which specific linux version I am using on this board, but also, how to remove it. What commands do I type through the terminal to do so? Also, once that is done and the linux is removed, I would like to install a compatible compiler with the processor. Does anyone know how I can go about in doing so? Or does anyone have any available links in how I can install a compatible compiler for this board? I'm very new to embedded development and I'm stuck on these two steps at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's is not a standardized method to determine the OS and distribution.

The `uname -a` command is pretty common and works for quite a few Unix like operating systems and often has hints to the actual OS. Linux specific are the `/proc/version` file and the common `lsb_release -a` command.

Red Hat and derivative distributions like CentOS will have a file `/etc/redhat-release`.

IIRC Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu have an equivalent `/etc/debian_version` file.

---

A quick look at the [specs](http://www.acmesystems.it/FOXG20) suggest that the Fox G20 comes pre-installed with a Debian version.

The [Fox G20 getting started guide](http://www.acmesystems.it/foxg20%5fgetting%5fstarted) seems to have quite a bit of useful instructions as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm still confused as to how to remove the OS. I've typed the `lsb_release -a` command, and get `Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.4 (squeeze)` as my description. I try to therefore remove it using `sudo apt-get --purge remove base-files`. But I'm not sure if the OS has actually been removed or not. Could you help me in that area? The `uname -a` command gives me `Linux foxboard 2.6.38`.

Comment: Reliably removing the OS from within the running OS is typically quite difficult ;) The specs show it is installed on the micro SD card, simply take that out and format it...

Comment: So by formatting the micro SD card, it will remove the OS on the board? Sorry I'm very new to all this!

Comment: Yes, the OS is installed on the SD card. Removing and formatting that is the same as removing the hard disk from your laptop or PC.  There's a bootloader in the 256KB of FLASH memory chip which won't be effected but since there won't be an OS, the bootloader will simply hang with an error message.

Comment: But if you don't actually know how to intentionally break it, will you be able to repair it?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! But what do you mean "intentionally break it" or "repair it". What is the "it" you refer to?

Comment: @Mahmoud he means that this will break your system. Removing the OS == breaking the system. Unless you know what you're doing (and it doesn't sound like you do) I would not recommend trying this. Why not install your compiler on the existing system? Also, you know you can't install a compiler without having an OS right? You can't replace an operating system with a compiler.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for your help. However, I'm removing an OS on an embedded board and I've learned that I will need to install a cross compiler toolchain on my Linux machine and compile my code using that toolchain and then loading the code onto my board (using an applicable bootloader for my board). I was confused before about installing a compiler on the board. But as an assignment, I have to remove the OS on the board and follow the steps I've mentioned (cross compiling etc.). Does this sound right to you?

Comment: Ah, so you will compile some kind of kernel or OS right? In that case, yeah, what you describe makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I will compile on a Linux machine before loading the code (executable) on the board. Thanks for the help! By the way, for some reason, I'm still having difficulties formatting my SD card. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right but I'm enterring `fdisk /dev/sdb1` where my SD card is located, then deleting the partitions (with `d`). But I don't know if that's doing the job.